# Process trackers which allow combining all subprocesses?

Tags: linux, operating-system, system-monitor, process-control

I want a GUI process monitor for Linux with which I can group together all separate processes which are part of a single running instance of Firefox, or Chromium, or other applications - so that I can see their RSS and CPU usage both separately and together.

It seems LXTask (0.1.8) and XFCE Task Manager (1.1.0) don't support this. GNOME System Monitor (3.22.2) also doesn't. What can I use instead?

Requirements:

- It needs to not depend on having an entire specific desktop environment
- Can run under LXDE, XFCE, Cinnamon
- Libre
- Gratis
- Lightweight